# What is the differences/changes between OFX 1.02 and OFX 2.03 formats?

Tags: ofx

What is the difference/changes between OFX 1.02 and OFX 2.03 formats?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like an awfully vague question, but one major change I can see right away from looking at the relevant specs is that in OFX 1.x, it doesn't look like closing tags are needed on some of the tags (I'm not sure which). For example, see the following request example from the v1.02 docs:

```
<OFX>
<SIGNONMSGSRQV1>
    <SONRQ>
        <DTCLIENT>19961029101000
        <USERID>123-45-6789
        <USERPASS>MyPassword
        <LANGUAGE>ENG
        <FI>
            <ORG>NCH
            <FID>1001
        </FI>
        <APPID>MyApp    
        <APPVER>0500    
    </SONRQ>
</SIGNONMSGSRQV1>

<BANKMSGSRQV1>
    <STMTTRNRQ>
        <TRNUID>1001    
        <STMTRQ>
            <BANKACCTFROM>
                <BANKID>121099999
                <ACCTID>999988  
                <ACCTTYPE>CHECKING
                </BANKACCTFROM>
            <INCTRAN>
                <INCLUDE>Y
            </INCTRAN>
        </STMTRQ>
    </STMTTRNRQ>
</BANKMSGSRQV1>
```

Notice how some of them don't have closing tags? That's apparently valid in 1.x. In v2.x, they moved to using a full XML format, so you have to have closing tags.